# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (424,16,3) into shape (128,160,3)

Tags: python, numpy

I was working with the code [`process_kitti.py`](https://github.com/coxlab/prednet/blob/master/process_kitti.py) by coxlab from GitHub in an Anaconda environment. Some of the function was deprecated in Python 3.6. Therefore I have changed the following line:

```
im = imresize(im, (desired_sz[0], int(np.round(target_ds * im.shape[1]))))
```

into

```
from PIL import Image    
im = np.array(Image.fromarray(im).resize((desired_sz[0], int(np.round(target_ds * im.shape[1])))))
```

Otherwise everything else remained the same.

Interestingly, while I ran this code, the following error:

```
Creating train data: 41396 images
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "process_kitti.py", line 104, in <module>
    process_data()
  File "process_kitti.py", line 84, in process_data
    X[i] = process_im(im, desired_im_sz)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (424,16,3) into shape (128,160,3)
```

I am a bit confused with the cause of such error. Thanks a lot with the help.

Comment: One tuple is the shape of the object on  the right.  The other is the shape where it's supposed to fit.  They don't match!

Comment: @hpaulj thanks! both answers from ExplodingGayFish and you solved the issue. Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do note that the `size` parameter in the `imresize` function from `scipy` is a 2-tuple of `(height, width)` while in `Pillow` package it is `(width, height)` so you might need to reverse the order

Source:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imresize.html

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html

Comment: This works! The problem indeed caused by the ordering of the argument. Changed it, works like a works like a charm! Thanks a lot!